# Ansible delegate_to: localhost task running on remote host

Tags: ansible

I have paly to copy the web server logs from remote machine to Ansible machine. At the end of the playbook, I want to find the file with pattern and remove it. in the task I have defined `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1` but this task is running one of the remote machine.

How to make these task run on only `localhost` and run once:

```
- name: Finds files and folders
  find:
    paths: "/tmp/"
    patterns: "access-*.tar.gz"
    recurse: no
    use_regex: yes
  register: result
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
  tags:
    - pulllogs

- name: display filename
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
  tags:
    - pulllogs
```

Output:

```
TASK [operate : Finds files and folders] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01]
 

TASK [operate : display filename] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    examined: 640
    failed: false
    files: []
    matched: 0
    msg: ''
```

Comment: Set ``use_regex: false``. The *patterns* doesn't seem like Python regex. Your code should work as expected, I guess. In the output, I don't see the delegation of the tasks either, but the code works.

Comment: settings this to false helped. `use_regex: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ansible 2.10 the delegation works as expected. In the output, I can't see the delegation either. But both plays, running at localhost and at delegated localhost respectively, show the same results. For example, given the archive at localhost

```sh
shell> sudo find /tmp -name 'access-*.tar.gz'
/tmp/access-01.tar.gz
```

and no archives at the remote host

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 sudo find /tmp -name 'access-*.tar.gz'
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: /tmp
        patterns: "access-*.tar.gz"
        recurse: false
        use_regex: false
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"

- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  tasks:
    - block:
        - find:
            paths: /tmp
            patterns: "access-*.tar.gz"
            recurse: false
            use_regex: false
          register: result
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: true
```

shows the same results at localhost and delegated localhost

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************

TASK [find] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - /tmp/access-01.tar.gz

PLAY [test_11,test_12,test_13] ********************************************

TASK [find] ***************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg:
  - /tmp/access-01.tar.gz

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
localhost : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_11   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Agree, it runs on local host, in display it shows first host in the inventory list.

Comment: Do you know if this output is corrected in the versions after 2.10? I mean, that "localhost is displayed when running with delegate_to: localhost.

Comment: I answer my own question. Tested with a 2.13.3 version of Ansible and it seems to display "ok: [XXXXX -> localhost] => {" which is a good thing. Much clearer!